# Dynamics crm Query expression Email Entity with to attribute

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, query-expressions

Hi I was stuck on how to query from email entity filter by email address in `to` field.

```
private static EntityCollection GetEmails(IOrganizationService service, string entityName, string emailaddress, ColumnSet cols)
        {

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "email",
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    //FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions = {
       new ConditionExpression {
        AttributeName = "statuscode",
         Operator = ConditionOperator.LessThan,
         Values = {
          1
         }
       }
      }
                },
                LinkEntities = {
      new LinkEntity {
       LinkFromEntityName = "activitypointer",
        LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
        LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
        LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
        LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression {
         FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
          Conditions = {
           new ConditionExpression {
            AttributeName = "addressused",
             Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
             Values = {
              "agus@yahoo"
             }
           }
          }
        }
      }
     }
            };
            return service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        }
```

By right, there is a record where `to` field contain `agus@yahoo`. But this method return zero records.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ConditionOperator.Like` along with `%` instead of `ConditionOperator.Equal`

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/akmscrmblog/archive/2016/01/16/use-like-operator-in-queryexpression)

**Update**:

I quickly did a query in XrmToolBox Fetchxml builder & copied the QueryExpression equivalent from there. Yes, you have to use `activityparty` and not `activitypointer`. (not sure how your query didn't fail for column not found!?)

```
// Instantiate QueryExpression QEemail
var QEemail = new QueryExpression("email");
QEemail.TopCount = 50;

// Add columns to QEemail.ColumnSet
QEemail.ColumnSet.AddColumns("activityid", "activitytypecode");

// Define filter QEemail.Criteria
QEemail.Criteria.AddCondition("activitytypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 4202);

// Add link-entity QEemail_activityparty
var QEemail_activityparty = QEemail.AddLink("activityparty", "activityid", "activityid");

// Add columns to QEemail_activityparty.Columns
QEemail_activityparty.Columns.AddColumns("addressused");

// Define filter QEemail_activityparty.LinkCriteria
QEemail_activityparty.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("addressused", ConditionOperator.Like, "%arunvinoth%");
```

Comment: Thanks, but still return zero record. Does my link entities correct ?

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness, here is the code..

```
private static EntityCollection GetEmails(IOrganizationService service, string entityName, ColumnSet cols)
    {

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "email",
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                //FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                Conditions = {
                    new ConditionExpression {
                        AttributeName = "statuscode",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = { 1 }
                    }
                }
            },
            LinkEntities = {
                new LinkEntity {
                    LinkFromEntityName = "email",
                    LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
                    LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
                    LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
                    LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression {
                        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                        Conditions = {
                            new ConditionExpression {
                                AttributeName = "addressused",
                                Operator = ConditionOperator.Like,
                                Values = { "%" + "agus@yahoo" + "%" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        return service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    }
```

Thanks to @Arun